# Fit text into a div

Tags: css

I am trying to show only a segment of my text, based on the div size.  Following related posts I found here I used this:

```
example {
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The problem is that the last line of text is often being chopped in the middle (horizontally), depending on the screen size.  What is the best way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably use a gradient opacity band in the lower part? The line would fade out in a graceful way.

Answer (score 0):

I went another route:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

---

## Here's with hiding the content and wrapping correctly:

```css
body 
{
   background: #006699;
}
#main 
{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #fefefe;
    border: 2px solid #336699;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <b>Note:</b> 
    Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the flex-wrap property.
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <b>Note:</b> 
    Safari 6.1 (and newer) supports an alternative, the -webkit-flex-wrap property.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## But something's missing; the ellipsis!

***[Kyle Simpson from HTML5 Hub tells us why :](http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/)***

> ... `text-overflow:ellipsis` only works on single line of text. That is, you can’t simultaneously have the text wrap to subsequent lines ***and*** have it ellipse at the end of the last line.
>
> **Bummer**, because that’s exactly what you’d probably want, like for instance displaying news items or tweets in a compact space, you’d want to show the first 2 lines and then ellipse the rest, possibly to reveal on hover or on click.

Comment: Nope, still the same outcome.

Comment: Set width to a fixed width and see then.

Comment: now all the lines are truncated and the last one is still chopped.

Comment: No offense, but even your code snippet is showing a bit of a chopped line a the bottom.

Comment: @user2573222 - right ... b/c you can't use text-overflow: ellipsis on multiple lines.  That's what the explanation underneath talks about. Read that article.

Comment: yeah I understand.  Pretty crazy that there's not simple/elegant solution to this.

Comment: JavaScript. It's in his article

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your style:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: This turns it into a single line text instead of multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but if you can keep the height of the div a multiple of the line-height of the text (for e.g., 15 x 5 = 75), your won't chop mid-line.

```
.example {
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  height: 75px;
}
```